# Program in c++ tell if a number is integer or float

Tags: c++

I used function overload to check if an input number is integer or float. However I get this following error:
error: call of overloaded 'retNr(double)' is ambiguous|

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

void retNr(int x)
{
    cout << "The entered number is an integer. " << endl;
}

void retNr(float x)
{
    cout << "The entered number is a float. " << endl;
}

int main()
{
    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> nr;
    retNr(nr);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where is `nr` declared? Then you'll see the problem with what you're trying to do.

Comment: it will always call the overloaded function which matches the declared type of `nr` -- it will not depend on the input (like in javascript)

Comment: What you need to do, presumably, is read in to a string, and parse that.

Comment: You can input to a `std::string` value, and use the [`std::stof`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/stof) function if a valid float was read.

Comment: Static typing does not work like you think it does.

Answer (score 3):

Read from cin into a string and then check the string for the presence of a decimal point. If there is a decimal point, call **atof()** on the string to convert it to a float, otherwise call **atoi()** to convert it to an integer.

Comment: Note `atoi()` should be called first, to check if the input was a valid `int`, if this fails you can check with `atof()` if the input was a valid `float`.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I think you must still check for the dot. ["The string can contain additional characters after those that form the integral number, which are ignored and have no effect on the behavior of this function."](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/atoi/)

Comment: For completeness I would also check for the presence of the letter 'e', as a number of the form "1e-2" is a valid float.

Comment: And of course, you wouldn't use `atof` or `atoi`, but rather `strtod` and `strtol`.  Actually, the simplest solution might be to use `strtol`, then see if the end pointer points to `'.'`, `'E'` or `'e'`, and have another go of it using `strtod` if it is.

Comment: Alternately, `nr` could be read as a `float` every time, and then the program found check whether `(nr == floor(nr))`. If that equality is true, the number is an integer, even if the user entered something lime "12.0000".

Answer (score 2):

Make some small change in:

```
void retNr(double x)
{
    cout << "The entered number is a double. " << endl;
}
```

Remember to declare your `nr` variable.

```
double d = 1.0;
int i = 1;

retNr(d);
retNr(i);
```

Answer (score 1):

You will have to initialize `nr` first.

Then you can use integer read & check it with a float if there is dot, ie ch=='.'

Thus, your program will be like this:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int nr = 0; char ch;
    cout << "Please enter a number: " << endl;
    cin >> nr;
    cin.get(ch);
    if(ch=='.')
    {
        cout << "The entered number is a float. " << endl;
    }
    else
    {
         cout << "The entered number is an integer. " << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's not too clear what you're asking for.  If you really want
to know whether a number is an integer or not, then use `modf`
on it:

```
bool
isInt( double d )
{
    double dummy;
    return modf( d, &dummy ) == 0.0;
}
```

If you're reading a number, then read it as a `double`, and then
use the above.

If you want to trigger off the format of the input (i.e.
`"10.0"` will be treated as a floating point, even though it is
an integer), then read the input as a string, then try to
convert it to `int`; if this eats all of the input, then it was
entered as an `int` (no decimal or exponent), otherwise, try the
same thing treating it as a `double`:

```
std::string entry;
std::cin >> entry;

char const* end;
long i = strtol( entry.c_str(), &end, 10 );
if ( *end == '\0' ) {
    //  entry was entered in integral format...
} else {
    double d = strtod( entry.c_str(), &end );
    if ( *end == '\0' ) {
        //  entry was entered in floating point format...
    } else {
        //  entry wasn't a number...
    }
}
```

I'd advise against this, however; it will only confuse your
users if `0` isn't `0.0`.

Comment: This is off topic, but as a newb, what's the purpose of passing &dummy rather than just dummy to modf?

Answer (score 1):

You may use abs() function for this issue.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>

int main()
{
   double input;
   scanf("%lf",&input);

   int absulate = abs(input);
   printf( (input==absulate)? "It is integer\n" : "It is float");

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Program in c++ not in C.

Answer (score 1):

```
float num = 7;
int n = (int)num;
float n1 = (float)n;
if(num == n1)
{
    cout << "Integer\n";
}
else
{
    cout << "Not Integer\n";
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The question is wrong in its essence: A number it is not a float or an integer, but could be represented as a float or as an integer ( of course certain representation has some limitations )
So if I wrote '`10`' why should I say this is an integer? Could be a float too! Just if I want to use it as a float I would represent it as a float.

Comment: As a mathematician I would say, all integers are also real numbers, but not all real numbers are integers.